# Integral (close form?)

Tags: integration, analysis

I'm struggling to evaluate the following integral:

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+5x^8+6x^{10}+7x^{12}}{\sqrt{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+x^4 \right )\left ( 1+x^6 \right )}}\,dx$.

I see that the integrand is even, thus the integral can be re-written as: $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}=2\int_{0}^{1}$, which does not help at all. Applying the sub $u=1-x$ is useless because it would result in a giant mess.

Do you see a pattern or an alternate approach?

Comment: Try partial fractions.

Comment: How am I supposed to apply partial? How can this be done? Some more hints?

Comment: @VladimirVargas Is this a hint or a random guess?

Comment: The second one. It seemed to me that multiplying both in the numerator and denominator by that square root, then using partial fractions to have "mini"-integrals would ease a bit the work. But now I see that those mini-integrals, each containing the square root are difficult to solve as well.

Comment: As I said , my intuition says that a closed form is far away. Wolfram gets a numerical approximation. It gives this integral approximately equal to $5$ plus little more. But I don't think it is that easy to evaluate.

Comment: @VladimirVargas If you wish to communicate a random guess to the OP, please do not phrase it as if it was a hint leading to a solution (in the present case it is not).

Answer (score 1):

I'll play and see if
I can find anything interesting.

$I
=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+5x^8+6x^{10}+7x^{12}}{\sqrt{( 1+x^2 ) ( 1+x^4  ) ( 1+x^6  )}}\,dx$

Let $y=x^2$.
Then
$dy = 2x\, dx
$
or
$dx
=\frac{dy}{2x}
=\frac{dy}{2\sqrt{y}}
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
I
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1+2y+3y^2+4y^3+5y^4+6y^5+7y^6}{\sqrt{y( 1+y ) ( 1+y^2  ) ( 1+y^3  )}}
dy\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{g(y)dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}
\\
\end{array}
$

where
$g(y)
=1+2y+3y^2+4y^3+5y^4+6y^5+7y^6
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
f(y)
&=y( 1+y ) ( 1+y^2  ) ( 1+y^3  )\\
&=y\left( ( 1+y^2  ) ( 1+y^3  )+y ( 1+y^2  ) ( 1+y^3  )\right)\\
&=y\left( 1+y^2+y^3+y^5+y(1+y^2+y^3+y^5)\right)\\
&=y\left( 1+y^2+y^3+y^5+y+y^3+y^4+y^6\right)\\
&=y\left(1+y+y^2+2y^3+y^4+y^5+y^6\right)\\
&=y+y^2+y^3+2y^4+y^5+y^6+y^7\\
\end{array}
$

Noting that

$\begin{array}\\
f'(y)
&=1+2y+3y^2+8y^3+5y^4+6y^5+7y^6\\
&=(1+2y+3y^2+4y^3+5y^4+6y^5+7y^6)+4y^3\\
&=g(y)+4y^3\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
I
&=\frac12\int_0^1 \dfrac{g(y)dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1 \dfrac{(f'(y)-4y^3)dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1 \dfrac{f'(y)dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}
-2\int_0^1 \dfrac{y^3\,dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}\\
\end{array}
$

I'll stop here;
this seems like a good start.

Any errors here
should be reported
to the appropriate committee
for immediate remediation.

Comment: That's a good start! If everything is in place , then the last two integrals appearing , the first one is pretty straight forward. The second one I don't know. Thank you!